# OData with Web API/Entity Framework - define controller name for entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using OData in WebAPI (with Entity Framework models) and it seems to be working a treat. However I have an entity/controller called NominalAccounts, where the controller is called 'NominalAccountsController', the DB entity is 'NominalAccount' and the OData path I *want* to use is 'nominal_accounts' (i.e. http://test/api/nominal_accounts ). So I have the below code in the Startup class:

```
 builder.EntitySet<NominalAccount>("nominal_accounts");
```

But this seems to fail because the it looks for the controller with an underscore. Is there a way to define, for an entity set, which controller it should look for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your setup looks like, but I have one `controller` for each entity. And for my controllers to have a specific endpoint I simply use a [`ODataRoutePrefix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.odatarouteprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)-prefix:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Query;
using System.Web.OData.Routing;

[ODataRoutePrefix("nominal_accounts")]
public class NominalAccountsController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual IQueryable<NominalAccount> Get(ODataQueryOptions<NominalAccount> q)
    {
        return _your_odata_source;
    }
}
```

And my config like so:

```
IEdmModel model = GenerateModel();
config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: model);
```